# IBM Watson Assistant: Using newly generated API details still deploys the old assistant on my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

When trying to integrate my latest Watson assistant chatbot into my Wordpress site I continue to see my last Watson assistant chatbot on the site even after configuring the Watson assistant Wordpress plugin with my new API details for my latest Watson chatbot. After multiple attempts of updating the API details within the plug-in I still continue to see my older version. I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong here, if anyone could please guide me on the right path that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Reads like either a caching problem, or looking right when the changes are being made left.

Comment: Why would this be a caching problem?

Comment: Provided you are making the changes in the right place (and I am not convinced that you are), then if you make a change at A, and use B to look at A, but B is still showing old content, then B is using a cache to fetch the old content and not going back to A to fetch revised content.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a basic question but have you updated the skill that's plugged into that assistant? You may have updated the API details but you need to make sure that you make your assistant point to the latest skill workspace.